# Trying to grab the current search query value from Search Box input using Javascript (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, search, sharepoint-search, classic-experience

I have a SP Web Part search box on a number of pages and, in order to create a link that load a page with that search box auto-populated with the existing search, I've been using JS.

I've managed to get it working if I put the exact ID of the input field in the script but that id changes from page to page.

However, using the firstChild or children[] JavaScript functions, it seems to change the behavior and the script which grabs the initial default value of the input ie. "Search..." instead of the current value of the input.

This is what I've got:

```
function getCurrentValue() {
  var searchQuery = document.getElementById("SearchBox").children[0].children[0].value;
  console.log(searchQuery);
}


<div id="SearchBox">
  <div id"randomGeneratedId">
    <input type="text" value="Search..." id="anotherRandomGeneratedId"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Run!" onClick="getCurrentValue();">
```

Outside of SharePoint this seems to work fine - returning the current value of the input.

If there's an out-of-the-box solution, that'd be great too (although, we have no access to SP Designer).

Answer (score 1):

Try using either of below selector for your input element:

```
var searchQuery = document.querySelector("#SearchBox input[title^='Search']").value;
console.log(searchQuery);
```

OR

```
var searchQuery = document.querySelector("#SearchBox input").value;
console.log(searchQuery);
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi @txchou Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way.